# Is it possible to update an open CSV file?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a friend who, as part of his work, has to work around filtering some raw data text files (actually logs sent from a server). Now I suggested helping him with it using python, and so far it wasn't too complicated. However, I hit a brick wall when he told me that some of the data *has* to be added manually.

So my first thought was maybe I'd create a csv file, which is both easy to deal with in python, and looks like a normal excel for my friend. Every time a new log arrives,the script updates its name into the csv file and my friend can easily add more information. Every row looks something like this:

logName, , , ,

the empty spaces are left for my friend to fill, and then he has a second script which collects all the data. But here's the problem - when you open a csv file with excel, you can't update it using python. So every time he wants to update he needs to open save and close, open save and close. It's a headache.

Now I know this is a problem with excel and not the csv itself, because If I read the file using sublime it live-updates after the script is run. Excel has a sharing option, but its reserved for xls files and not csv.

I tried looking in the internet and found some really complex stuff, and it's stating to look impossible. any ideas?

Comment: do you have to use csv's? There are some many other options to store data that are designed for multiple users..

Comment: What you're describing is one of the reason databases exist. Python has a great one built in: SQLite... http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: I understand, but I'm talking about the part that's before that. I should have mentioned that the other part of this project was building him a database and a nice presentation with a django web app. This data is going to reach a DB eventually, but I need something simple and easy to use to update some of the data on the go. I don't wanna make it too hard for him. I want to give him a familiar and really simple interface, as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said if I were going to do this I would create an Access database and have your Python script(s) insert and update the data in that and then have your friend do the manual bit via Access itself.

Have a look at [PyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) for how to do this - there are many questions on here with examples of connecting to an Access database.

Comment: I never used Access but I'll check it out, it sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively if you did want to use Excel you could try something like the following to insert the log data into the open Excel document.

```
import win32com.client
import time

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")                             
xl.Visible = True
Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
Sheets = Workbook.Sheets

for i in xrange(1, 1000):
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 'LogFile' + str(i)
    #Simulate a delay in the next log being written
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: The thing is, I know how to use the win32 api and I also have some experience with xlrd, I know that that is a possible solution, but it's ugly and messy. I'm looking for a simpler solution if possible